# Express.js app working perfectly on local machine, but produces 404 when app.post() fires on Netlify

Tags: express, http-status-code-404, netlify, express-router

I'd like a user to be directed to a specific page (promo1.html, promo2.html, etc...) when a corresponding promo code is entered into the form field. This runs nicely when I use it on localhost: but after deploying to Netlify it gives me a 404 when I enter a code.

I've tried everything I can think of, is there something wrong with my code or is this a Netlify formatting/routing issue and how do i resolve it?

https://github.com/extrajake/telus_distributor

It's ok that the promo codes are hardcoded in the file for the moment, I'll deal with making that dynamic later.

```
const express = require('express');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/submit', function (req, res) {
  const codes = ["1NKCI", "V3L7R", "60HPC", "8SF6L", "AHG08"];
  const codes2 = ["2WEMV", "KWWNI", "XNB7X", "6BN2T", "Y2FOK"];
  const codes3 = ["YJYZL", "6HNP2", "V9FF8", "8SF5L", "5B23I"];
  const codes4 = ["UVUNU", "1N5UL", "IINVK", "AEZNP", "HM2NM"];
  const codes5 = ["KGFIA", "XI28K", "2QQ8K", "9Y4HK", "DMQJT"];

  if (codes.includes(req.body.field)) {
    res.redirect('/promo1.html');
  } else if (codes2.includes(req.body.field)) {
    res.redirect('/promo2.html');
  } else if (codes3.includes(req.body.field)) {
    res.redirect('/promo3.html');
  } else if (codes4.includes(req.body.field)) {
    res.redirect('/promo4.html');
  } else if (codes5.includes(req.body.field)) {
    res.redirect('/promo5.html');
  } else {
    res.send('The code is invalid');
  }
});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

neltify.toml

```
[build]
 
  functions = "functions" # Adjust this directory name if needed

[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

I've tried adding redirects to netlify.toml, placing npm run build in Netlify app and moving my app.js file in public, src, functions and root, nothing.

Here's the page:
https://main--musical-manatee-2e343b.netlify.app